# How to validate if a string is json in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, validation

I'm building a simple app and want to be able to store json strings in a db. I have a table Interface with a column json, and I want my rails model to validate the value of the string. So something like:

```
class Interface < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :json

  validates :name,  :presence => true,
                    :length   => { :minimum => 3,
                                   :maximum => 40 },
                    :uniqueness => true

  validates :json, :presence => true,
                   :type => json #SOMETHING LIKE THIS
                   :contains => json #OR THIS    
end
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I suppose you could parse the field in question and see if it throws an error. Here's a simplified example (you might want to drop the double bang for something a bit clearer):

```
require 'json'

class String
  def is_json?
    begin
      !!JSON.parse(self)
    rescue
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Then you could use this string extension in a custom validator.

```
validate :json_format

protected

  def json_format
    errors[:base] << "not in json format" unless json.is_json?
  end
```

Comment: And all went green, thank you! Great response time too:) I had been trying to do something like this but my Rails skills are a little dusty.

Comment: Hmm, this is strange. I have rspec tests, one of which requires a valid json string as the value for json, and these all green. But my cucumber tests fail, and also testing the view in the rails server fails, stating is_json? is an undefined method. I've placed the validation class you suggested below my model, is that wrong?

Comment: I guess there's different opinions but it seems that most people are placing their core class extensions in `config/initializers/` as `*.rb` (naturally) where they get loaded automatically after Rails is loaded. Another option is the `lib/` directory, but then you'll have to tell Rails still to load your file.

Comment: The solution works great and I made an upvote but allow me a short rant: extending basic objects with own methods is generally considered not best practice. I would prefer to implement the is_json? method in a helper class or module and provide the 'suspected_json' string as an argument to the method. Although it is really elegant to be able to use self here :)

Comment: @awenkhh The 2014–me would have to agree with you rather than with the 2011–me. Maybe a case for refinements ;) ?

Answer (score 18):

Currently (Rails 3/Rails 4) I would prefer a **custom validator**. Also see https://gist.github.com/joost/7ee5fbcc40e377369351.

```rb
# Put this code in lib/validators/json_validator.rb
# Usage in your model:
#   validates :json_attribute, presence: true, json: true
#
# To have a detailed error use something like:
#   validates :json_attribute, presence: true, json: {message: :some_i18n_key}
# In your yaml use:
#   some_i18n_key: "detailed exception message: %{exception_message}"
class JsonValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def initialize(options)
    options.reverse_merge!(:message => :invalid)
    super(options)
  end

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    value = value.strip if value.is_a?(String)
    ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(value)
  rescue MultiJson::LoadError, TypeError => exception
    record.errors.add(attribute, options[:message], exception_message: exception.message)
  end

end
```

Comment: I actually like this idea better than the accepted answer. just how about using MultiJson.load(value) instead of ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(value)? It would then also run into the rescue block...

Answer (score 16):

The best way is to add a method to the JSON module !

**Put this in your config/application.rb :**

```
module JSON
  def self.is_json?(foo)
    begin
      return false unless foo.is_a?(String)
      JSON.parse(foo).all?
    rescue JSON::ParserError
      false
    end 
  end
end
```

Now you'll be enable to use it anywhere ('controller, model, view,...'), just like this :

```
puts 'it is json' if JSON.is_json?(something)
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced another problem using Rails 4.2.4 and PostgreSQL adapter (pg) and custom validator for my json field.

In the following example:

```
class SomeController < BaseController
  def update
    @record.json_field = params[:json_field]
  end
end
```

if you pass invalid JSON to

```
params[:json_field]
```

it is quietly ignored and "nil" is stored in

```
@record.json_field
```

If you use custom validator like

```
class JsonValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    begin
      JSON.parse(record.json_field)
    rescue
      errors.add(:json_field, 'invalid json')
    end
  end
end
```

you wouldn't see invalid string in

```
record.json_field
```

only "nil" value, because rails does type casting before passing your value to validator. In order to overcome this, just use

```
record.json_field_before_type_cast
```

in your validator.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't fancy enterprise-style validators or monkey-patching the String class here's a simple solution:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  validate :json_field_format

  def parsed_json_field
    JSON.parse(json_field)
  end

  private

  def json_field_format
    return if json_field.blank?
    begin
      parsed_json_field
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e
      errors[:json_field] << "is not valid JSON" 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the idea that you would you substitute for json_field - as in: `validate :options_format` or `parsed_options`?

Answer (score 1):

Using JSON parser, pure JSON format validation is possible. `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(value)` validates value `"123"` and `123` to true. That is not correct!

```
# Usage in your model:
#   validates :json_attribute, presence: true, json: true
#
# To have a detailed error use something like:
#   validates :json_attribute, presence: true, json: {message: :some_i18n_key}
# In your yaml use:
#   some_i18n_key: "detailed exception message: %{exception_message}"
class JsonValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def initialize(options)
    options.reverse_merge!(message: :invalid)
    super(options)
  end


  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.is_a?(Hash) || value.is_a?(Array)
      value = value.to_json
    elsif value.is_a?(String)
      value = value.strip
    end
    JSON.parse(value)
  rescue JSON::ParserError, TypeError => exception
    record.errors.add(attribute, options[:message], exception_message: exception.message)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and elegant way, imo. The top upvoted answers will either return true when passing a string containing integers or floats, or throw an error in this case.

```
def valid_json?(string)
    hash = Oj.load(string)
    hash.is_a?(Hash) || hash.is_a?(Array)
rescue Oj::ParseError
    false
end
```