# How to validate a json type attribute

Tags: json, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.0.4 w/ Postgres

Ruby 2.1.1

I am using a model with a JSON type attribute.

here the migration

```
def change
    create_table :my_models do |t|
      t.json :my_json_attribute, :null => false

      t.timestamps
    end
end
```

I want to validate this attribute in my form before saved or updated in the database.

Today I am getting a nasty JSON parser error (JSON::ParserError) instead of a friendly message on my form .. I am purposely giving an incorrect JSON input in my form to check if validation works and if I get a friendly message asking to verify the JSON string ... but I am not even sure how to check whether attribute_in_json_format was called

In my model class, I have something like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate_presence_of :my_json_attribute

  validate :attribute_in_json_format

protected
  def attribute_in_json_format
    errors[:base] << "not in JSON format" unless my_json_attribute.is_json?
  end
end
```

Created an initializer string.rb:

```
require 'json'

class String
  def is_json?
    begin
      !!JSON.parse(self)
    rescue
      false
    end
  end
end
```

I am not getting any success ... I am still going to the MultiJson::ParseError instead of going through the validate.

Any suggestion?

I took my inspiration from this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594257/how-to-validate-if-a-string-is-json-in-a-rails-model)

Comment: If you get a json parse error, then your input string is corrupted/invalid. you need to look at that string and figure out what's wrong. Either it got generated wrong originally, or it got corrupted in transit. But whatever the cause, fiddling with your ruby isn't going to help, because that's not where the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit late, but I think that your approach is in the right direction. However, you don't need to monkey-patch the `String` class. You can do this:

```
validate :attribute_in_json_format

private

def attribute_in_json_format
  JSON.parse(my_json_attribute.to_s)
rescue JSON::ParserError
  errors[:base] << "not in JSON format"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `store_accessor` would help.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :my_jason_attribute
  validate_presence_of :my_json_attribute
...
```

Here is the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html). Check the NOTE:

> NOTE - If you are using PostgreSQL specific columns like hstore or
>   json there is no need for the serialization provided by store. Simply
>   use store_accessor instead to generate the accessor methods. Be aware
>   that these columns use a string keyed hash and do not allow access
>   using a symbol.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that does look promising. I will try ASAP.

Comment: Another related very important **note**: _NOTE: The default validations with the exception of uniqueness will work. For example, if you want to check for uniqueness with hstore you will need to use a custom validation to handle it._